# can i omit zero bytes of last int of decimal when persisting it as bytes

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Jon Skeet's "C# in Depth" [states](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Decimal) that .NET's `decimal` last `int` always has two first zero bytes. By some experiments it appears to be true. I'm gonna store `decimal` as bytes. In order to reduce memory cost can i omit these 16 bits of zeros when persisting decimal? Obviously, when reading bytes and translating them to a number I'll add those bits.

I'm unsure because I want to see solid proof that such representation format of decimal will not change in .NET and I can not find such words anywhere.

Comment: Actually, it also would be useful to know why these "excess" zeros exist in `decimal` in the first place. I'd appreciate answer to this question as well.

Comment: If it's not explicitly specified in the C# spec that this is the case, I would advise against it. It may be true now, but if the implementation changes, it may not be true in the future.

Comment: Well yeah, obviously if it is not specified, i won't experiment with data format due to same reason. I'm asking this because I made some research, did not find desired information and wondering whether I missed it, or it really does not exist.

Comment: How will you get the bytes for the decimal? BitConverter.GetBytes() as of 4.7.2 does not have an overload that takes a decimal. BinaryFormatter also writes `value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` if value is of type decimal, so in a binary representation of a class with decimal members, these members are serialized as strings.

Comment: You will probably gain more bytes by storing the decimals as their ASCII string representation bytes, assuming that the decimal numbers you have has an average string size less than eight. (decimal 1.45 takes up to 8 bytes, but "1.45" ASCII only 3)

Comment: I convert `decimal` to bytes using `GetBits` + `BitConverter` methods
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19055.net-convert-system-decimal-to-and-from-byte-arrays.aspx

Comment: Did you try for decimal.MaxValue and decimal.MinValue?

Comment: The idea of storing decimals as strings seems prone to errors to me. Though two decimals 1.450m and 1.45m are equal, but their bytes representation differ. And I can not truncate trailing zeros because this might be just what user wants - store decimal specifically with given precision. So I'd have to store string of unpredictable length which is not convinient for bytes manipulation and might lead to mem leaks.

Comment: Max/MinValue works with `GetBits` + `BitCoverter` as well.

Comment: If you want to save space I would recommend using compression. Either regular DEFLATE or lz4 if speed is more important.

Comment: @idementia Are you trying to store a value exactly as the user typed it or something? If so, how are achieving that while storing as bytes? I don't understand any of your arguments against storing as a string. Can't truncate trailing zeros? You're already storing as bytes. How are you maintaining trailing zeroes that way?  Bytes manipulation? Mem leaks? Where do these things come into play?

Comment: @itsme86 decimal bytes representation format respects precision. Meaning, 1.45m and 1.450m decimal numbers will have different bytes representation. So, I am not loosing precision storing decimal as bytes and I always know that stored value takes only up to 16 bytes which would not be guaranteed if I stored it as string.